# Android PhoneGap with Native Controls

Tags: android, layout, webview, cordova

I am trying to build an Android application with PhoneGap.

I need to be able to use the PhoneGap WebView (super.appView) and all of its javascript magic but I also need to display some native UI controls around the WebView.

This post goes part way to providing a solution [Android PhoneGap Plugin, UI tabbar, resize WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174434/android-phonegap-plugin-ui-tabbar-resize-webview)

Has anyone managed to implement PhoneGap with a native UI?

I will also be using a GestureOverlayView but thats another story ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//creates super.appView and calls setContentView(root) in DroidGap.java
init();
//just an empty LinearLayout
layoutId = R.layout.blank;
view = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(layoutId);
view.addView(your_component_here);
view.addView((View) appView.getParent()); //adds the PhoneGap browser at index 1
//accesses the browser at index 1. Tells browser to not fill view
view.getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
setContentView(view);
```

I would struggle to tell you how this works, all I can tell you is that it does and it is all my own work.

Setting the view to a different colour can help you to see what is going on too....

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Working with PhoneGap-1.0.0.jar the latest release so far.

Comment: could you place a screenshot of what the outcome will be ?

Answer (score 8):

A more cleaner approach:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Create native view with UI controls.
View header = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.header, null);

// PhoneGaps WebView is located inside a LinearLayout.
// The protected (and therefore inherited) variable root
// references this LinearLayout. Add your native Views
// to this variable.
root.addView(header);

// Create WebView and add it automatically to the LinearLayout.
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: And you can add native components beneath the WebView as well?

Comment: Yes, just add another view after super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); with root.addView(footer);

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: Currently Phonegap (Cordova) version 1.5. But an update to version 1.6 is planned. I will update my post if this approach isn't possible anymore with version 1.6.

Comment: Starting with Phonegap (Cordova) version 1.9 one can embed the Cordova Webview component in a native application. See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can embed native controls within HTML by using the plugin.

Call the native method which contains your native view from HTML page using plugin.

e.g. `window.plugins.anatomyPlugin.showAudio();`

I use this for showing audio player design in native.

This [guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) from PhoneGap may be helpful.