# Add loading indicator/progress bar to Phonegap Android splashscreen

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, webview, splash-screen

I have a PhoneGap 1.4.1 / jQueryMobile 1.0.1 / Android project which is showing the res/drawable/splash.png just fine, and the splashscreen goes away once the WebView is loaded.

I would like to add some sort of progress indicator percentage text to the splashscreen but have been unsuccessful so far.

I have had success with this in the past by using a normal webview like so:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        myLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
myWebView.loadUrl(...);
```

but all that was just a layout with a progress indicator text and a background image that would get updated with:

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        myLoadingView.setText(progress+"%");
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how I can add this functionality to the existing PhoneGap implementation, or know how I can replace the PhoneGap one with an implementation of my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've found a solution (not a full solution, but a spinner solution). Inside DroidGap subclass you should add this line:

```
super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Wait, Loading...");
```

Here is my full example

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        // Display a native loading dialog.  Format for value = "Title,Message".  
        // (String - default=null)
        super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Wait,Loading Demo...");

       super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
      }
}
```

There are several properties you could set up in this section, please see this code: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-android/branches/WebSockets/framework/src/com/phonegap/DroidGap.java

Answer (score 5):

I finally managed to add a progress bar to a PhoneGap webView which will show the progress (percentage) of the page load. Hope this helps you

As [this other answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9995855/969132), `appView` is located inside a `LinearLayout`. The protected (and therefore inherited) variable root references this `LinearLayout`. You can add your (whatever) native `View`s to this variable.

Here is how I did:

1. Create a layout in your res/layouts/

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
           style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:maxHeight="10dip"
           android:minHeight="10dip" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Follow all the steps you would normally follow for adding a WebView progress bar:

   ```
   final Activity activity = this;
   private ProgressBar progessBar1;
   ```
3. Add the layout you created:

   ```
   View footer = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.mainshop, null);
   root.addView(footer);
   ```

   If you add it after calling `super.loadURL(...);` it will be displayed at the bottom. If you add it before, the layout will be displayed before the appView.
4. After that you simply add this:

   ```
   progessBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

   this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) { 
               activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
               if(progress < 100 && progessBar1.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                   progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
               }
               progessBar1.setProgress(progress);
               if(progress == 100) {
                   progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
               }

               Log.d("Progress", progress+"");

            }
       });
   ```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know you can easily add a loading indicator to your splash screen by setting the `ShowSplashScreenSpinner` option to YES in your PhoneGap configuration file (PhoneGap.plist on iOS)

It shows a spinner in the middle of the splash screen while the app is loading

Edit: This only works with iOS.

Comment: This is interesting. I have added: <splash ShowSplashScreenSpinner="YES" /> to my /res/xml/phonegap.xml file but it doesn't add a spinner. I am unable to find the Android equivalents for the .plist but will keep hunting. Thanks

Comment: @darryn.ten the following line is an android equivalent for the `ShowSplashScreenSpinner` in PhoneGap: `<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />` add this line to your config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using a Activity that extends DroidGap, create a regular Android activity and put org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView in a layout file. It will give you much more flexibility.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android

Answer (score -1):

If you use jquery-mobile you can do:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
$('.ui-loader h1').html('<h1>Saving ... <span id="ui-loading-extra"></span>');
```

Then in onProgressChanged do:

```
$('#ui-loading-extra').text(progress  + '%');
```

Comment: This all happens before the webview has finished loading, before jQueryMobile is available.