# java.lang.NullPointerException from DroidGap > onCreate > setWebChromeClient & progressBar implementation

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-build

it has been years since my last Java class, not to mention never having written JAVA at work..

Anyways, I'm trying to get this Cordova app to render the loading widget on the splash screen while the javascript html + initial AJAX calls are being executed.

I've taken up the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395010/add-loading-indicator-progress-bar-to-phonegap-android-splashscreen) but I'm not doing something right... appView is there per [DroidGap.java](https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/blob/master/android/framework/src/com/phonegap/DroidGap.java) source, so that can't be null. In fact I have no idea what is pointing to null here.. perhaps I have this code in the wrong place?

Wish I had more time to dive into things here... if anyone has some suggestions I'm all ears, well, all eyes in any case.

There's this [pastebin post](http://pastebin.com/42MryXKe) that looks identical to the one above, so I've considered having the progressbar code outside of onCreate to no avail.

```
package com.Project.MainActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap
{
    final Activity activity = this;
    private ProgressBar progessBar1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View footer = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.main, root);
        root.addView(footer);
        progessBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) { 
                progessBar1.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                if(progress < 100 && progessBar1.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                progessBar1.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress == 100) {
                    progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }

                Log.d("Progress", progress+"");

             }
        });

        super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Wait, Loading...");
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

This code produces the output:

```
05-22 10:13:27.238: E/UpdateReceiver(11872): ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
05-22 10:13:29.988: E/dalvikvm(14200): could not disable core file generation for pid 14200: Operation not permitted
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Project.MainActivity/com.Project.MainActivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at com.Project.MainActivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
05-22 09:37:01.394: E/AndroidRuntime(13370):    ... 11 more
```

res/layouts/main.xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxHeight="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this.appView is null, but it shouldn't be per the super.onCreate(...) call as seen [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java;h=6e3d99d834fedf02bbbf812e929f30e34c682020;hb=refs/heads/master):

```
 313     /**
 314      * Create and initialize web container with default web view objects.
 315      */
 316     public void init() {
 317         CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(CordovaActivity.this);
 318         CordovaWebViewClient webViewClient;
 319         if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 320         {
 321             webViewClient = new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView);
 322         }
 323         else
 324         {
 325             webViewClient = new IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(this, webView);
 326         }
 327         this.init(webView, webViewClient, new CordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
 328     }
 329 
 330     /**
 331      * Initialize web container with web view objects.
 332      *
 333      * @param webView
 334      * @param webViewClient
 335      * @param webChromeClient
 336      */
 337     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 338     public void init(CordovaWebView webView, CordovaWebViewClient webViewClient, CordovaChromeClient webChromeClient) {
 339         LOG.d(TAG, "DroidGap.init()");
 340 
 341         // Set up web container
 342         this.appView = webView;
 343         this.appView.setId(100);
 344 
 345         this.appView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
 346         this.appView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
```

Comment: is `R.layout.main` the layout that contains `R.id.progressBar1` ? If so try doing your progress bar lookup like this: `progessBar1 = (ProgressBar) footer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);` also for clarity sake which line is 48?

Comment: line 48: this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { [...]

Comment: added the footer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); ...good catch! Still is complaining about the NullPointerException though.

Comment: clicked on All messages and noticed a few more errors at the top...     ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED and could not disable core file generation for pid 14200: Operation not permitted.. perhaps there's a permissions issue going on? Though, why would not being able to disable something generate an error (updated the error message dump above)

Comment: add a null check on `this.appView` seems like it is coming up null for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a NullPointerException is pretty straightforward : a variable is null and you're trying to access a field/method on it.

If the line 48 is

```
this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
```

there is a good chance appView is null.

I don't know Cordova, but You should probably check the DroidGap life-cycle and take a look at examples provided in the [Javadoc](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java;h=6e3d99d834fedf02bbbf812e929f30e34c682020;hb=refs/heads/master).

It seems you need to call super.init() at some point to initialize appView.

Comment: looks like the super.onCreate(...) calls the super.init().. thanks for the Javadoc link. Checking it out now...

Comment: looks like this might be an import problem. when i try to generate javadoc it complains a lot... "package android.content does not exist" and "cannot access android.content.BroadcastReceiver" and "package org.json does not exist" ... but no errors show in eclipse prior to running

Comment: What version of PG are you using?  Latest version require calling of init see line 81: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java