# Cordova Android Plugin with Native UI Control

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I was wondering if its possible to have UI controls in a Cordova Android Plugin? For ex. If I want to create a Button or a Textview on the fly in my native plugin.

In order to do this I need to get access to the current root layout. According to my knowledge, in Android, Cordova creates a LinearLayout on which it puts the CordovaWebView. Is it possible to get access to the root layout and add another view  (for button/text), so that Android will automatically adjust the next CordovaWebView. I also referred to the following  question 
[Android PhoneGap with Native Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320910/android-phonegap-with-native-controls)
However for current versions of Cordova, I cannot get access to CordovaActivity and the LinearLayout "root" from plugin.

After going through cordova docs it suggests to embed a cordova webview in a native app, but I want to add a native control inside a plugin to an app created using cordova.

Pardon me for being so verbose, but I want to make myself as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one or two views, you could just hardcode that into phonegap itself. But if you're looking to have native views in your app, take a look at phoenixsdk - https://phoenixsdk.com/ it's android+ios, all controls are native on both platforms, etc. It's still beta, but if it's something that you need, the release is in January 2015.